# How to automate the Ace Editor (send keys) using WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, ace-editor

In my application all the query editors are Ace editor and I need to type in queries using WebDriver. I have tried using send keys but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way I can send my input to Ace editor and thus automate?

Below is my HTML code

```
<div class="" ng-show="queryType=='Spark Query'">
    <pre class=" ace_editor ace-xcode">
    <textarea class="ace_text-input" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="opacity: 0; height: 18px; width: 7px; left: 4px; top: 0px;"/>
    <div class="ace_gutter" style="display: none;">
    <div class="ace_scroller" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="ace_content" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 659px; height: 334px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <div class="ace_layer ace_print-margin-layer">
    <div class="ace_layer ace_marker-layer"/>
    <div class="ace_layer ace_text-layer" style="padding: 0px 4px;">
    <div class="ace_layer ace_marker-layer"/>
    <div class="ace_layer ace_cursor-layer ace_hidden-cursors">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could somebody please suggest how to implement the sendKeys to AceEditor using webDriver

Answer (score 4):

It should be much easier to use the editor API than SendKeys. For example, here is a C# console app that lauches ACE home page and change the text in the current demo editor:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ace.c9.io/");
        driver.ExecuteScript("editor.setValue('the new text here');");
    }
}
```

`editor` is the variable in the page that corresponds to the ACE editor instance, and I've just used one of the first API samples detailed here : [Working with ACE](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto)

Comment: Thank you for ur quick response. Could please elaborate :( i am totally new to this.. I am using WebDriver using java . So for my above code how can i send my query ( Select * from the tableName) to the ace editor using webDriver commands. ?

Comment: i dint understand why you are navigating to ace.c9.io url and how can we enter the text value to our application Ace editor using this link  ??? could you please give more inputs. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is just a sample on how to automate ace editor. The sample navigates to the ace page and inputs the text directly in the ace editor in that page. It demonstrates how to automate ace editor with webdriver, without sendkeys, but using the ace editor API.

Comment: How can i use this  api with my java code ? when u mean editor.setValue , editor being an object , where will i define  ??? so before i sent value to the editor i should tell webDriver that this the editor.  Below is the code i tried. do i need to import any jar ?

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ace_content")).sendKeys("select * from Table");
 
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("editor.setValue('select * from Tablename');");

Comment: Code "editor.setValue('the new text here');" is executed inside browser. There is a global variable 'editor' available on page with editor.

Answer (score 3):

I've found using the following `sequence` on ace's `textarea` works reliably. `mouseDown`, `mouseUp` then `sendText`.

Click doesn't work reliably for me due to the way Ace works out if it should focus the textarea or not.

Thanks for your question, its nice to know I wasn't alone. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Both Becky's and Simon's answer doesn't work for me. Simon's in particular because I have multiple instances of the ACE editor on the page and the ACE instances are not leaked onto the window object (modern ES6 module encapsulation).

Here's what works for me (ace 1.2.6):

```
const ta = document.querySelector("textarea");
ta.value = "my text\nwith newline";
ta.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
```

In addition, if you have registered key commands, you may trigger them via native JS events again:

```
const e = document.createEvent("Event");
e.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
e.keyCode = 13  # Enter key
ta.dispatchEvent(e);
```

This works in PhantomJS 2. It would be nice if ACE made it easier to test out of the box, but oh well.